# Ant + Proguard provide android-support-v4.jar errors

Tags: android, eclipse, ant, proguard, android-compatibility

While building project using ANT 1.8.2 and proguarg 4.8.1

```
 [proguard] Unexpected error while evaluating instruction:
 [proguard]   Class       = [android/support/v4/view/AccessibilityDelegateCompat$AccessibilityDelegateJellyBeanImpl]
 [proguard]   Method      = [newAccessiblityDelegateBridge(Landroid/support/v4/view/AccessibilityDelegateCompat;)Ljava/lang/Object;]
 [proguard]   Instruction = [18] areturn
 [proguard]   Exception   = [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Can't find any super classes of [android/support/v4/view/AccessibilityDelegateCompatIcs$1] (not even immediate super class [android/view/View$AccessibilityDelegate]))
 [proguard] Unexpected error while performing partial evaluation:
 [proguard]   Class       = [android/support/v4/view/AccessibilityDelegateCompat$AccessibilityDelegateJellyBeanImpl]
 [proguard]   Method      = [newAccessiblityDelegateBridge(Landroid/support/v4/view/AccessibilityDelegateCompat;)Ljava/lang/Object;]
 [proguard]   Exception   = [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Can't find any super classes of [android/support/v4/view/AccessibilityDelegateCompatIcs$1] (not even immediate super class [android/view/View$AccessibilityDelegate]))

BUILD FAILED
E:\adt-bundle-windows\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:864: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:     Can't find any super classes of [android/support/v4/view/AccessibilityDelegateCompatIcs$1] (not even immediate super class [android/view/View$AccessibilityDelegate])
```

`android-support-v4.jar` is in class path and project dependecies...
From `Eclipse` all `but debug` version is built OK.
Ant display those errors...

How do avoid this? I understand if `Eclipse` builds this OK, the `Ant` have to build too..

**P.S.** My project is android-10 target and I don't want and can't make it target-16 if somebody'll advise...

Answer (score 2):

what about try to add these to your proguard.cf?

```
-libraryjars   libs/android-support-v4.jar
-dontwarn android.support.v4.**    
-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }  
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }  
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.**  
-keep public class * extends android.app.Fragment
```

Comment: -dontwarn android.support.v4.**
-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }
is enough

Answer (score 2):

You should specify a target SDK in your `project.properties` that in this case contains 'android.view.View$AccessibilityDelegate' (SDK level 14 or higher). ProGuard's shrinking/optimization/obfuscation need at least the same base SDK that was used for compiling the application *and* its libraries. The support library was compiled against this more recent SDK, so ProGuard needs it as well.

You can still specify a different target/min/max SDK in your `AndroidManifest.xml`, for running the application. You should of course make sure that the application is indeed compatible with those specified SDKs.

Comment: I'm having this same issue and your advice solved it.  My concern is this:  the documentation stipulates that specifying a target version below SDK 14 enables certain legacy options (e.g. options menu).  If I specify a build target of SDK 14 will that cause my application not to have these compatibility features when run on a SDK 14+ device?

Comment: @user190758 If I'm not mistaking, the documentation refers to the target version in AndroidManifest.xml, which you can set freely.